# Highlighting tabs/pills

Tags: angularjs

I made a tabbed interface (using pills in the top nav menu) and I want to have the tab stay highlighted once it's been clicked. However, right now this only happens if the user clicks it twice. My current code is as follows:

```
<span ng-repeat="u in users">
    <span ng-if="u.username === username">
        <span ng-if="u.permission === 'Admin User' || u.permission === 'Super User'">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="display:inline-block; padding-top: 34px;">
                <li ng-class="{active: selectedTab == 1}"><a ui-sref="repostag" ng-click="selectedTab = 1;">Repos Auto Tags</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{active: selectedTab == 2}"><a ui-sref="assetstag" ng-click="selectedTab = 2;">Assets Manual Tags</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{active: selectedTab == 3}"><a ui-sref="publish" ng-click="selectedTab = 3;">Publish</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{active: selectedTab == 4}"><a ui-sref="admin" ng-click="selectedTab = 4;">Admin</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{active: selectedTab == 5}"><a ui-sref="config" ng-click="selectedTab = 5;">Config</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{active: selectedTab == 6}"><a ui-sref="tagactivities" ng-click="selectedTab = 6;">Tag Activities</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{active: selectedTab == 7}"><a ui-sref="locallogs" ng-click="selectedTab = 7;">Local Logs</a></li>
                <li style="font-weight: bold;"><a ui-sref="login">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="u.permission !== 'Admin User' && u.permission !== 'Super User'">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="display:inline-block; padding-top: 34px;">
                <li ng-class="{active: selectedTab == 1}"><a ui-sref="repostag" ng-click="selectedTab = 1;">Repos Auto Tags</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{active: selectedTab == 2}"><a ui-sref="assetstag" ng-click="selectedTab = 2;">Assets Manual Tags</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{active: selectedTab == 3}"><a ui-sref="publish" ng-click="selectedTab = 3;">Publish</a></li>
                <li style="font-weight: bold;"><a ui-sref="login">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

So my two questions are:
1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Is what I'm doing even best/acceptable practice? I thought I could use $state.current.name as selectedTab value but that didn't work.

FYI I'm repeating some of the list items because I discovered if I only made the admin-centric pills conditionally visible, the menu items will wrap and I'll end up with more than one menu line. Like I said - if there's a better way to do the same thing...

Comment: It appears to be working: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5ovOHdGu6SMzNg5SzIzz?p=preview) You need to rethink your security though. Don't send all user info to every client.

Comment: does it work without the `ui-sref` attributes?  If it does, the problem is probably in how you have the states/views configured.  Judging by how none of your `ui-sref` point to any *child states* (which would infer that this menu is not in any persisting view and is therefore getting reloaded in each state change), I would guess that this is most likely it.

Comment: I would guess that you probably could use `$state.current.name`, but you wouldn't use it against `selectedTab`, you would use it like: `ng-class="{active: $state.current.name == 'repostag'}"` (example for the item linking `ui-sref="repostag"`)

Comment: Changing ui-sref to href made no difference.